# Rails Profiling Weirdness - Inconsistent Render Times Reported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, newrelic

This is a long shot, but I was wondering if anyone has any idea:

I'm profiling my Rails app with the NewRelic RPM in development, and I'm seeing some really long view load times. The thing is, the next time I load the page, it's an entirely different set of views that's taking a long time to load.

**Page Load #1**
[image]

**Page Load #2**
[image]

I'm not doing anything too crazy. Rails 4, Ruby 2, partial caching with memcached (but I'm seeing the same errors even when caching is disabled.)

Any idea what's up with this? It's not just an error with the logs, as the application is indeed taking a while to render this page. Not an error specific to NewRelic's RPM either -- I see the same thing with rails_panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is an issue with the Garbage Collector. (I knew there had to be a reasonable explanation for this.)

There's a great post going on about this issue on the [Discource Meta Forum](http://meta.discourse.org/t/tuning-ruby-and-rails-for-discourse/4126). The tl;dr is to set your `RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT` to a higher value, to avoid garbage collections during renders.

Comment: If you're using Unicorn, look at the Unicorn::OOBGC module, which will disable GC during requests and instead run it between requests.